# Check Database while debugging test in django

Tags: django, database, debugging, django-testing

I need to check the database during a test.

I change the settings to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test_db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
}
```

So now when I run:

```
python3 manage.py test --keepdb  accounts
```

I finish with a test_db.sqlite3, the problem is that this database after and during the test is empty all the time.

I am executing this code:

```
    def test_add_members(self):
    pp_castrillon = GrupoPolitico(nombre_grupo="PP", alcance=self.test_concejo)
    pp_castrillon.save()

    print(pp_castrillon.miembros.count())

    user_a = User(username="A_test")
    user_b = User(username="B_test")
    user_c = User(username="C_test")

    user_a.save()
    user_b.save()
    user_c.save()

    user_a.residencia.add(self.test_concejo)
    user_b.residencia.add(self.test_concejo)
    user_c.residencia.add(self.test_concejo)

    pp_castrillon.grupo.user_set.add(user_b)
    pp_castrillon.miembros.add(user_a)
    pp_castrillon.grupo.grupo_de.add_member(user_c)

    pp_castrillon.save()

    for miembro in pp_castrillon.miembros.all():
        print(miembro)

    for miembro in pp_castrillon.grupo.grupo_de.miembros.all():
        print(miembro)

    for miembro in pp_castrillon.grupo.user_set.all():
        print(miembro)


    print(user_a.miembro.all())

    print(pp_castrillon.miembros.count())
```

This function test is inside a class extending django.test.TestCase

How could I do this?

Comment: A far as I know,  any test runs in transaction which is never committed,  so you can't see changes to test database outside the test.  This is done so multiple tests in a row does not breaks each other.

Comment: And there is a way to connect to the database while you are in a debug point inside the test? Or to do some manual queries against it ?